# Setting default application to open files through FileZilla?

Tags: default-programs, filezilla, sublime-text

I have installed Sublime Text 2. I have set all the default files to open with this. However, when I open a file from my server using FileZilla (by right-clicking and file and then click "View/Edit") it still opens up in Gedit.

Can I change this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can set it by going to `edit > Settings`, and then going to the `Filetype Associations` section and adding the filetypes and the editor you want.

Comment: here is an example to associate python files with sublime `py "/path/to/sublime_text"`

Comment: `html  /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text`  ubuntu 14.04

Comment: This resolution is incomplete,  without @mrcktz's answer

Comment: Its an accepted answer but its totally incomplete. common files are always available in filetypes. there are some other confirgurations that are definitely missing in this answer.

Answer (score 18):

Go to `Edit -> Settings` and navigate to `File Editing`.

Choose `Use custom editor` and browse the executable file of `Sublime Text 2`.

Close the dialog by pressing <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Done!

Screen shot of a mac application
[image]

Comment: Combination of this answer and answered by @Spice should be the best and accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

Write in the terminal : `dpkg -L sublime-text` to check the sublime current location.

And then try to find something like this : `/usr/bin/subl`

Now you just need to go to - ***edit - settings - Filetype Associations***

And write the following :

```
html /usr/bin/subl
```

to open in the same window

and...

```
html /usr/bin/subl -open
```

to open in the new window :)

Answer (score 4):

If you installed **sublime-text** via **snap** on **Ubuntu 18.04** you can use

```
/snap/bin/sublime-text.subl
```

Answer (score 2):

as per direction given in [set default editor for filezilla in ubuntu](http://guruquest.net/question/set-default-editor-for-filezilla-in-ubuntu/) 16.04 , you can modify for default editor.

You have to change the preference as for the executable file exist in ***/usr/bin/$PATH*** for editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it by going to **edit -> Settings** in filezilla, and then go to **Filetype Associations** section and add the filetypes and the editor you want for them.

```
html /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text
```

*/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text*  is executable path of the sublime text editor. You can enter your own path of executable file.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 16.04.
First, find out where your Sublime-Text is located:
go to usr/bin and double click sublime-text.
You should see something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

/opt/sublime_text_2/sublime_text --class=sublime-text-2 "$@"
```

Copy just the beginning of line 2:

```
/opt/sublime_text_2/sublime_text
```

Add html to the front:

```
html /opt/sublime_text_2/sublime_text
```

Go to edit -> Preferences -> Filetype associations and paste that in.

Answer (score 1):

All the above posts are correct, i am just sharing with pictures for better understanding and I am using `ubuntu 16.04` with `updated FileZilla`.

Run this command. `dpkg -L sublime-text`
[image: step1]

[image: step2]

Press  `CTRL + L` and Search for /usr/bin sblm and select.
[image: step3]

Answer (score 1):

You can find directory your installation, in my case, the directory of install of sublime is:

```
snap/sublime-text-/24/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text
```

Case you have installed your FileZilla, can you open your old configure file, for it, you can use the commands:

> vim ~/.config/filezilla/filezilla.xml

or

> vim ~/.config/filezilla/filezilla.xml

in the file, you search the word "editor" using the command:
/editor

[look a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGOD5.png)

In line has the directory of your old text editor.

Answer (score 0):

- click 'view/edit' on a particular text file
- choose 'Use custom editor'
- click 'Browse'enter the location 'usr/bin'
- select subl file

Answer (score 0):

for me `dpkg` command didn't work. I manually had to find `sublime-text` installed folder and it was in **snap** folder of root.
I pasted this line in custom Editor. please check if `sublime_text` is available in path or update it as per your `sublime_text` path. Rest settings as per image reference attached please.

```
./snap/sublime-text/18/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text
```

[File-Editor Path Update FileZilla Image Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsEOC.png)

P.S : I'm on Ubuntu'18.

Answer (score 0):

This is for those ubuntu user who installed sublime-text-editor by snap wanted to use in filezilla, they can use this command in "filetype associations".

php /snap/bin/subl

Answer (score -1):

**Here are steps to do it quickly -**

Step 1: Open Filezilla > Then Click on Edit Menu. Under Edit Submenu Click on Settings ( As Shown in Screenshot Below)

[image]

Step 2: In Settings Window Click on "Use Custom Editor" Radio Button -> Then Click on Browse Button To Choose your Default Text Editor / Code Editor. ( As Shown in Screenshot Below )

[image]

Step 3: In Browse Window Navigate to Installation Directory of your TextEditor You wish to use. In my use I am using "Brackets" Text Editor So I navigated to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\Brackets.exe" that is installation directory of my text editor.

[image]

Step 4: Then Click on Ok Button to close Settings Wizard.

If your's Specific files like php files, cfm files, css files or js files still not opening in your default editor Then **WAIT THERE IS ONE MORE Step you need to follow**

[image]

Step 5 - In Settings Window that you opened in step 1 -> Click on FileTypeAssociations -> It will show list of all files extensions configured to open in specific text editor. See screenshot below -

[image]

You can see in above screenshot some of my filetypes are associated still with notedpad.exe. for example - i was trying to open .php file from ftp in my default text editor but its associated with notepad.exe that's why it was not opening.

In order to open php file in my default editor from FTP I changed below line

```
php C:\Windows\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE
```

to this line below -

```
php "C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\Brackets.exe"
```

I have done it for php you can do it for any other filetype you wish and also for any other texteditor you wish.